# exe not working after new libraries but works in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, exe, libraries, launch4j

I have a java project which basically imports .xls Files and generates .pdf-Files. I usually update it with new code. Then export runnable JAR file and make an exe with launch4j (3.12). This workflow worked several times without issues.

Now I added poi4.1.1.jar with several jar-libraries coming with..After adapting the code (now imports .xlsm Files), I could compile and run the program in Eclipse without any problems. But after generating the exe-File, the programm starts running but failed reading the .xlsm-File..

I guess it's something with my adding of libraries, but can't find the problem...

I added libraries with: Properties > Java Build Path > Add External JARs > Apply

I export with: Export > Runnable JAR file > Extract required libraries into generated JAR

Does anybody have an idea?

Cheers,

Comment: Are you using maven along with launch4j plugin to create exe ?

Comment: Do you have any stack trace to show? If you dont, try to cach it in order to get a more specific error

Comment: I dont use maven and I have launch4j not as a plugin, it's a seperate program on my laptop..:
Dont have any stack trace yet...however I dont get en error, it seems that when it comes to read the .xlsm-File , it just reads " " and so there is nothing to convert to pdf...

had this problem when adapting the code in eclipse, but solved it and now have it again with the exe-File..